# Nginx configuration for domain name

Tags: nginx

I have setup my website with nginx configuration and it is working on this adress : http://178.128.44.106/
Howewer when i try to link a domain name to it, I arrive on a NGINX configuration page : http://lawoodtech.fr/

Here is my nginx configuration :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 178.128.44.106 lawoodtech.fr www.lawoodtech.fr;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/djangoadmin/pyapps/woodtech;
    }
    
    location /media/ {
        root /home/djangoadmin/pyapps/woodtech;    
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Comment: lawoodtech.fr resolves to 165.232.102.232 - not to 178.128.44.106 !!!

Comment: Thank you, I made the change, and still not working.

Comment: Did you restart nginX after you made changes to the config?

Comment: Yes i did the restart.

Comment: If you do not have other server blocks in your config - you may add `default_server` to the `listen` directive.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain to me how to do that ?

Comment: Something like this `server { listen 80 default_server; }`

Comment: I resolved this problem by deleting what was on the default server block, the domain entries that I had added. Thank you for the help.